# Does anyone know of any studies comparing juvenile and adult abundance data for an ontogenetic reef fish?

Tags: oceanography, models, literature-request, estuary

I'm trying to look into relationships between juvenile Hogfish which recruit in sea grass habitats to adult abundance data that move to deeper offshore reef and hard bottom habitat. I have data from both areas but on different scales. The juvenile data is local and regional, the adult data is the entire west Florida shelf. There are some scaling issues there and I was wondering if anyone knows of any studies that are similar to this, especially if they used trawl data? The data I'm looking at has about 87% zeros.

I've found studies that  cover ZIP and staged analysis such as: `Yogita S. Wagh & Kirtee K. Kamalja (2018) Zero-inflated models and estimation in zero-inflated Poisson distribution, Communications in Statistics - Simulation and Computation, 47:8, 2248-2265, DOI: 10.1080/03610918.2017.1341526`

What I can't seem to find is anyone comparing juvenile abundance and year class data to adult abundance using similar but different size gears in different environments and/or at different scales. I've found something close here: `Ali Arab, Mark L. Wildhaber, Christopher K. Wikle & Casey N. Gentry (2008) Zero-Inflated Modeling of Fish Catch per Unit Area Resulting from Multiple Gears: Application to Channel Catfish and Shovelnose Sturgeon in the Missouri River, North American Journal of Fisheries Management, 28:4, 1044-1058, DOI: 10.1577/M06-250.1`